# How can I filter my contacts by user that it belongs?

Tags: django, model

I need to show names that belong only to one user..

**models.py**

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, unique=False)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, unique=False)
    father_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, unique=False)
    dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, unique=False)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/photos/', null=True, blank=True)
    email = email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True, unique=False)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=False, blank=False, unique=False)
    contact_belongs_to = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
    def post(self, request:HttpRequest)->HttpResponse:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Contact.objects.create(name=form.cleaned_data['name'], surname=form.cleaned_data['surname'], father_name=form.cleaned_data['father_name'], dob=form.cleaned_data['dob'], photo=form.cleaned_data['photo'],
                 email=form.cleaned_data['email'], phone_number=form.cleaned_data['phone_number'], contact_belongs_to=request.user).save()
            return HttpResponse('OK')
        else:
            return render(request, 'contacts/contact_form.html', context={'form':form})
```

this is how 'contact_belongs_to' takes value->user

And when user wants to see only his own contacts I should filter them by 'contact_belongs_to' or no?

Could you help please...

Answer (score 1):

You can go about it in 2 ways:

1. Using the related name in the User object: `request.user.contacts`
2. Filter `Contact` using `contact_belongs_to`: `Contact.objects.filter(contact_belongs_to=request.user)`